# Remote desktop authentication fails from one client, but not from another

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop, authentication

I've been reliably using remote desktop from my Win 10 home machine (VPN using Dual Authentication) to my Windows 10 office machine for months (COVID work from home, very restricted environment at work).  All of a sudden, I'm getting a message:

> Authentication error has occurred. The Local Security Authority cannot
> be contacted. Remote computer xxxxxxxxxxx This could be due to an
> expired password . Please update your password if it has expired

I hauled my butt to work, after getting clearance to do so, rebooted, made sure my password was current  -- and it was.  Nothing odd I could find on the host machine.

No love trying to RDP in.  My credentials are correct, as when I use a wrong password, I get a simple authentication error.

Searching out the error suggests a bunch of host-side fixes, so just for giggles, I tried RD-ing in from a Win 7 laptop, and it worked like a charm -- no issues.  This leads me to wanting to handle this as a client-side issue.  The only thing I could think of was a difference in local resource handling, but disabling local resources didn't help it.

I'm sort of at a loss for ideas.  I suppose next steps would be to try a third party client, or somehow repairing the windows client, but wanted to ask about the possibility that this could even be a VPN issue (both client machines using anyconnect, 4.6.01103).  I'd like to avoid working on the host, if at all possible.

Update:  In response to the great suggestion that a credential cache was doing me in, I created another account on the client machine, and used that account to remote desktop in.  Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relaxing the requirements for Network Level Authentication as described in https://windowsreport.com/local-security-authority-cannot-be-contacted/  worked!

I'm not sure why my two RDP clients behaved differently, but suspect it might be because the laptop is a work laptop, and might have been configured for access on that network.

Comment: This is very useful and could help others I think. I was going to suggest NLA myself but discounted it as you normally get an explicit message saying that's what it is. Evidently though there can be circumstances where that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible Windows is caching some credentials at some level you're not aware of (TERMSRV for example), and the cache has become corrupted.

You can see which credentials are cached using `Credential Manager` (Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager). Here you can examine each of the cached credentials in detail, and edit or delete them as required.

Before embarking on the above, I'd suggest creating a temporary second local account for yourself on your computer, and trying out the RDP while logged on to the new account. If this succeeds, you will have isolated the problem to your user profile and you can then check the credential caching and also anything else  in your user profile you suspect may be the cause.

Comment: Is this cache on the host side or client side?

Comment: @ScottSeidman it's client-side.

Comment: Created a new user on the client machine, and I get the same error when I try to RD in.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, tried the same solutions. No luck...

But... after downloading the "fancy" new version of Microsoft Remote Desktop, from the MS Store here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

I managed to connect!

As previous answers suggested, this is almost certain a credential/certificate kind of error. I a parallel world this would be like the RSA fingerprint has changed on a Linux SSH connection I suppose.

I have not found any way to purge all related data, and I would love to do that, because I do not like the new client's UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

Assumedly the error has a lot of issues that can cause this type of error. I just experienced this on a computer in my company. While I was able to login with a few other accounts without any issue there was one account which was requested to connect via remote desktop to the one computer which got this error.

The solution, in this case, was rather simple: The user was limited in our active directory to only log in to this one machine. This, however, blocked the remote desktop connection for this case.

So if you are in a company environment definitely worth to have a look at your Logon Restrictions (Log On To).